# Why only 1 map and 1 reduce task and 1 node is used in a Hadoop job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have configured a 3-nodes-cluster to run wordcount mapreduce program. I am using a book, whose size is 659 kb (http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/20417) as the test data. Interestingly, in the web UI of that Job, only 1 map, 1 reduce and 1 node is involved. I am wondering if this is because the data size is too small. If yes, could I set manually to split the data into different maps on multi nodes?

Thanks,
Allen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default block size is 64 MB. So yes, the framework does assign only one task of each kind because your input data is smaller.

1) You can either give input data that are more than 64 MB and see what happens.

2) Change the value of `mapred.max.split.size` which is specific for the mapreduce jobs
(in mapred-site.xml or running the job with the `-D mapred.max-split.size=noOfBytes`) 
or

3) Change the value of `dfs.block.size` which has a more global scope and applies for all the HDFS. (in hdfs-site.xml)

Don't forget to restart your cluster to apply changes in case you are modifying the conf files.

Comment: Thank you very much Artem! I was just wondering if you have seen any performance profile of Hadoop running on block size very small? Does it have some merit to do that?

Comment: @AllenLin You're welcome! I think it really depends on your job and your data ( many small files vs few large files). So it all leads to your `InputFormat` and the above properties. Now, for a Wordcount example with 659 kb it is probably too small too make a case. But generally you have the following tradeoff for a task (map or reduce): **preparation cost everytime** vs **overhead by assigning huge blocks**. I guess a balance is needed :)